# Why have a lost tables when moving from phpmyadmin to local MySQL Workbench

Tags: drupal, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, mysql

I have a Huge database in phpmyadmin. It have 1500 tables because I'm using Drupal. I used the command

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] [databasename] > [filename.sql]
```

To create a .sql file on the server. It took some time but was 100% complete. 
I then tried to copy the file to my local machine with Filezilla, it kept crashing and stopping so I used the command

```
scp [my_username]@[my_host]:[filename.sql] /some/local/directory.sql
```

This took a couple of hours but also said It was 100% complete. After this I opened MySQL workbench and imported from the file on my local machine. When the import was finished I have 1024 tables. I thought this was less than it should be and checked phpmyadmin with this sql command

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = <MyDatabaseName>;
```

This command returned table like this

[image: table]

So from this result I'm missing 484 tables. Where have they gone? are they meaningless tables or will this cause problems if I try to deploy?

My thoughts were that one of these commands leave behind some tables that Drupal creates because it sees them as pointless or broken.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: If you still have the backup on the original server, verify that the file was transferred intact.  `grep '^CREATE TABLE' filename.sql` will list the create table statements in the file (probably including some dummy tables for views), so you could start there and see if whether the missing tables are actually in the file, or not.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot So I ran the command `grep '^CREATE TABLE' filename.sql > createtable.txt` and copied the file down. Its just like you said the mysqldump command works really well it has all the tables in there.
That says to me that its probably some kind of limit with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Workbench is pretty terrible.  For restore, the mysql command line client is probably the best approach.  `mysql [args] < filename.sql` ... or, you can watch the restore in action with something like `perl -pe 'warn length($_) < 132 ? $_ : substr($_,0,129) . "...\n"' filename.sql | mysql [args]`, where `[args]` would be similar to the args to `mysqldump`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I used BASH (Locally this time on the file i downloaded) to run `grep '^CREATE TABLE' filename.sql > createtable.txt` just to double check that `scp [my_username]@[my_host]:[filename.sql] /some/local/directory.sql` copied my .sql file correctly from my server, turns out that it didn't copy everything down properly thats why I'm missing 400 tables. I wouldn't have found it without your grep command so say something about `scp` not copying correctly and put your `grep` cmd up and I'll accept it. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Great.  I'll post that at my first opportunity.